# How to get div height after add jquery append without using css overflow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get div height after I append some element this last,without using css overflow.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="wall"></div>
```

Javacript Code:

```
var walldown = setInterval(walldownfn, 10000);

    function walldownfn() {

        $.post("/php/post.php", function(data, status){
          $("#wall").append(data+"<br>");

        });
        var awrap = document.getElementById("wall");
        alert(awrap);
        }
```

Alert Output:

```
[object HTMLDivElement] or 0 height
```

ajax response data is HTML code.

Example :

```
<div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try `$("#wall").height()`?

Comment: yeah but that is also get 0 height always

Comment: You need to call it inside the function, after you append the content.

Answer (score 0):

By using [`$("#wall").height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) you get every timelapse the div hight See code bellow ( console instead of alert)

```js
var walldown = setInterval(walldownfn, 1500);

var returned_data = '<div class="card" style="width: 20rem;"><img class="card-img-top" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSQythd0ly14qbZd7YEJ9WreTX4-dBQw7vfGS33ZXbTQRJjE1AHITKZE5g" alt="Card image cap"><div class="card-block"><h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4><p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card\'s content.</p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a></div></div>';
function walldownfn() {

  $.post("https://httpbin.org/post", {text:returned_data},function(data, status){
      $("#wall").append(data.form.text);
      console.log("height : "+$("#wall").height());
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wall"></div>
```

Comment: This is not working when use ajax. My main purpuse is use ajax sorry for uninformed it. when use br is only get new line height.

Comment: @ind this is not what was mentioned in the question, please reformulate your question , waht do you mean by use ajax ? you grabe info using ajax then you're rendering it in that div ?

Comment: year you are correct after ajax get data rendering to the div after that i want that div height. I always get 0 without using br. If I use br it get break line height only about 12px not contain height

Comment: give me an example of your returned data ?

Comment: I you dont make your div `css word-wrap:break-word;` it'll always return the same height  because the output data is set in inline

Comment: are you sur you put the `$("#wall").height()` inside ajax response !
see my answer , every thing works well !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var walldown = setInterval(walldownfn, 10000);

function walldownfn() {
    $.post("/php/post.php", function(data, status){
        $("#wall").append(data+"<br>");
        alert($("#wall").height());
    });
}
```